# Setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in a Haskell Stack+Nix Project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

### Problem

I am running a Haskell project on NixOS (using `stack`) that makes use of `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (in case it matters: it's a wayland compositor project that runs with an X11 backend). When my program launches:

```
stack exec my-compositor-project-exe # nix is enabled by default
```

I get an error:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment
```

However if I run with `--no-nix-pure`, I don't get an error:

```
stack --no-nix-pure exec my-compositor-project-exe
# ... no error ...
```

But is that really the best way to fix this error?

Note that when I run `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in a NixOS terminal I get

```
echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1000
```

and when I run `nix-shell` within my Haskell stack project I also get

```
[nix-shell:~/my-project]$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1000
```

so it's quite a mystery why I get this error at all.

**Question:** What is the proper way to solve this problem?

### Context

In case it matters [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is some information about about what `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` means:

> There is a single base directory relative to which user-specific runtime files and other file objects should be placed. This directory is defined by the environment variable $XDG_RUNTIME_DI.
>
> ...
>
> $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR defines the base directory relative to which user-specific non-essential runtime files and other file objects (such as sockets, named pipes, …) should be stored. The directory MUST be owned by the user, and he MUST be the only one having read and write access to it. Its Unix access mode MUST be 0700.
>
> ...
>
> If $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set applications should fall back to a replacement directory with similar capabilities and print a warning message. Applications should use this directory for communication and synchronization purposes and should not place larger files in it, since it might reside in runtime memory and cannot necessarily be swapped out to disk.

The specific FFI call in my program which yields the error is a call to `wl_display_add_socket` (wayland function) which has at the top of its body:

```
WL_EXPORT int
wl_display_add_socket(struct wl_display *display, const char *name)
{
  runtime_dir = getenv("XDG_RUNTIME_DIR");
  if (!runtime_dir) {
    wl_log("error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment\n");

    /* to prevent programs reporting
     * "failed to add socket: Success" */
    errno = ENOENT;
    return -1;
  }
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nix purity feature in Stack doesn't work for everything, as you have noticed. Some environment variables are simply required for certain programs to interact with their environment, so it doesn't make sense to use the Nix integration in pure mode. The way I see it, is that `--nix-pure` is generally only suitable for compilation and incidentally works for some simple programs.

If you feel adventurous, you could try to explicitly pass environment variables through your `shell.nix`, by adding this line to your shell derivation:

```
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = builtins.getEnv "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
```

However, I wouldn't bother and just call `stack exec` with `--no-nix-pure`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wanted to press against your conclusion a bit though: doesn't using `builtins.getEnv "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"` keep things explicit? Why not prefer that to `--no-nix-pure`?

Comment: It does. It's a matter of taste and/or requirements. My shell already has 86 variables, many of which relate to desktop integration. To me that's a good indication that I will not be able to foresee what exactly is going to be used by my app's libraries and/or child processes. That approach will break things by default in the future and on other people's systems.